# Using dropDown menu to assign values to variables with knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

My goal is to use an if statement to give a value from another variable on my code.

HTML

```
<div id="countryContainer">
    <div class="label">
        Country:
    </div>
    <select id="countryDropDown"
        data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry">
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var mxLocations = [
 {title: 'Monterrey', location: {lat: 25.6475262, lng: -100.4524278 }},
 {title: 'Tulum, Quintana Roo', location: {lat: 20.2114185, lng: -87.4653502 }},
 {title: 'Tijuana', location: {lat: 32.5335808, lng: -117.1236801 }},
 {title: 'Guadalajara', location: {lat: 20.676856, lng: -103.344773 }}
];
var usLocations = [
  {title: 'Laredo', location: {lat: 30.3079827, lng: -97.8934848 }},
  {title: 'Venice Beach', location: {lat: 33.9799948, lng: -118.478614 }},
  {title: 'Miami', location: {lat: 25.7825453, lng: -80.2994983 }},
  {title: 'Wichita', location: {lat: 37.6647979, lng: -97.5837763 }}
];

var home = [
  {title: 'Laredo', location: {lat: 30.3079827, lng: -97.8934848 }}
];

var allLocations = (mxLocations.concat(usLocations)).concat(home);
var locations = ""

function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(this.value);
}

// Knockout Constructor
var Country = function(name) {
        this.countryName = ko.observable(name);
    };

    var viewModel = {
        availableCountries : ko.observableArray([
            new Country("All Locations"),
            new Country("Home"),
            new Country("Mexico"),
            new Country("USA")
        ]),
        selectedCountry : ko.observable() // Nothing selected by default
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This is what I want to accomplish, if a value from the dropDown menu is selected I want to give the value of a variavle to another variable

```
function locations() {
    if (dropDownValue == "All Locations") {
        var locations = allLocations;
    } else if (dropDownValue == "Home") {
        var locations = home;
    } else if (dropDownValue == "Mexico") {
        var locations = mxLocations;
    } else if (dropDownValue == "USA") {
        var locations = usLocations;
```

I've been looking in all over the place to accomplish this with no result I hope you can address me to the right dirrection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`subscribe`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly-subscribing-to-observables) to the `selectedCountry` observable. The callback function passed as a parameter to the `subscribe` will be called every time `selectedCountry` changes.

Here's a working snippet:

```js
var mxLocations = [
 {title: 'Monterrey', location: {lat: 25.6475262, lng: -100.4524278 }},
 {title: 'Tulum, Quintana Roo', location: {lat: 20.2114185, lng: -87.4653502 }},
 {title: 'Tijuana', location: {lat: 32.5335808, lng: -117.1236801 }},
 {title: 'Guadalajara', location: {lat: 20.676856, lng: -103.344773 }}
];
var usLocations = [
  {title: 'Laredo', location: {lat: 30.3079827, lng: -97.8934848 }},
  {title: 'Venice Beach', location: {lat: 33.9799948, lng: -118.478614 }},
  {title: 'Miami', location: {lat: 25.7825453, lng: -80.2994983 }},
  {title: 'Wichita', location: {lat: 37.6647979, lng: -97.5837763 }}
];

var home = [
  {title: 'Laredo', location: {lat: 30.3079827, lng: -97.8934848 }}
];

var allLocations = (mxLocations.concat(usLocations)).concat(home);
var locations = ""

var Country = function(name) {
  this.countryName = ko.observable(name);
};

var viewModel = {
  availableCountries: ko.observableArray([
    new Country("All Locations"),
    new Country("Home"),
    new Country("Mexico"),
    new Country("USA")
  ]),
  selectedCountry: ko.observable()
};

viewModel.selectedCountry.subscribe(function(selectedValue) {
  if (selectedValue.countryName() == "All Locations") {
    locations = allLocations;
  } else if (selectedValue.countryName() == "Home") {
    locations = home;
  } else if (selectedValue.countryName() == "Mexico") {
    locations = mxLocations;
  } else if (selectedValue.countryName() == "USA") {
    locations = usLocations;
  }
  console.log(locations);
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="label">
  Country:
</div>
<select id="countryDropDown" data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: 'countryName',
                   value: selectedCountry">
</select>
```

Click on `Run code snippet` to test it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adiga